# Modify page-title in Page parent dropdown to include permalink

Tags: block-editor, page-attributes

I have several identical page-titles that makes it difficult to choose the correct page-parent.
How can i add the permalink to the title in the combobox-page-parent dropdown to make it easier to separate the different pages?

I want something like this:
[image]